# Correct way to use Publish Pileine Artifact , Download Pipeline Artifact and Deploy to Azure webapp

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-devops, yaml

First of all I'm building a proof of concept demonstrating a build and deploy  (CI/CD0 in Azure Devops.
It is and ASP.NET 4.8 WebApp.

Using the tasks like **Download Build Artifacts** and **Publish Build Artifacts** and **Deploy Azure Webapp** I have no problems. But I read that the aforementioned tasks are being deprecated, but as soon as I use the new **Publish PipeLine Artifact** **Download Pipeline Artifact** and then **deploy Azure Web** App it doesn't work. It publishes and downloads the artifact but at the deploy azure web app stage it says it can't find the artifact. Truth is I have no idea what to fill out there. Googling everything I could find.
The azure deploy task gives me this error: #[error]Error:

> No package found with specified pattern: **D:\a\1\drop*.***
> Check i

I see the artifact actually downloads in the Download Pipelineartifact :

```
Download artifact to: D:\a\1
```

The actual question would be, what do I fill out the AzureWebApp@1 task with the package: *'$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/*.*'* (This is wrong but how do I make this right ?)

Very much appreciated

john

Here is  my YAML file code:

```
trigger:
- none
stages:

- stage: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'


  jobs:
  - job: Build


    variables:
      solution: '**/*.sln'
      buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
      buildConfiguration: 'Release'

    steps:
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '$(solution)'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'


    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
        artifact: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- stage: Deploy
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'

  jobs:
  - job: Deploy

    steps:

    - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
      inputs:
        buildType: 'current'
        artifactName: 'drop'
        targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'


    - task: AzureWebApp@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'tofreewebapp'
        appType: 'webApp'
        appName: 'freewebappdave'
        package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/*.*'
        deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

Comment: You're telling it to download to `$(Pipeline.Workspace)`, not `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop`. You can add a `script` step and do a PowerShell `gci -rec` or similar to enumerate all of the files and their paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\drop*.*
```

In the DownloadPipelineArtifact task, you downloaded the artifact to the `Pipeline.Workspace` path, but in the AzureWebApp task, the package path you specified is `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/*.*`. So the package was not found in the drop folder.

You can change the package path to `$(Pipeline.Workspace)`:

```
- task: AzureWebApp@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'tofreewebapp'
        appType: 'webApp'
        appName: 'freewebappdave'
        package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
        deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

Comment: Thanks!! Didn't work at first same error: D:\a\1\drop\<br/>Check . But... you did help me! I ran it with its your suggestion and got the aforementioned error but then when I commented out the Artifact name in the download task so drop is not specified it works!